# unable to invoke onclick for handlebar span class

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am facing problem with jquery onclick event and handlebars.

I have a handlebars template with ul,li and span elements forming a horizontal navigation menu.
I have a class defined for each of the span,writted css class for hover and selected.

Hover works fine but if i select the span element i dont get redirected to onclick event present in one of the included JS files.

This is my handlebar template.

```
var policyMenu = '<ul class="menu menuStyle"><li style="float:left;"><span class="mn selected" rel="environmental" title="Environmental policy" >Environmental</span></li><li style="float:left;"><span class="mn" rel="employee">Employee</span></li><li style="float:left;"><span class="mn" rel="customer">Customer</span></li><li style="float:left;"><span class="mn" rel="assets" >Assets</span></li></ul><br><br><br><div id="chart_container" style="min-width:39%;"></div>';
```

var policy_template = Handlebars.compile(policyMenu);

here is my JS code which is inside a included jS file

```
alert($('ul.menu li span.mn'));
 $('ul.menu li span.mn').click(function(){
    alert("menu function");
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') )
        return;     
    $('ul.nav li span.mn').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    selectedMenu = $(this).attr('rel');     
    alert(selectedMenu);
    //getResourceData(selectedSCA,'',0,0,0,0,0);
    displaySearchOptions();
});
```

I am unable to print the alert inside onclick.

Comment: Have you tried delegation instead? I don't have a clue about handlebars, but probably the elements are being added dynamically. Try: `$(document).on('click', 'ul.menu li span.mn', function() { });`

Comment: It does work http://jsfiddle.net/vCb5j/1/

Comment: @MelanciaUK Thanks that worked.But i still have a problem with CSS class not changing after selection.

Comment: @Aamir That is really strange..That its working in the fiddle.Is it because i have the script inside a included JS file?

Comment: You're returning if the element has the class `selected`, so it will never change.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Try wrapping your code in $(function(){...})

Comment: On jsFiddle it will work because there's no dynamic content manipulation, which occurs when using handlebars.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.I worked now.even the selected class.But still wonder why it didnt work using  $('ul.menu li span.mn').click(function(){}); but worked using $(document).on('click', 'ul.menu li span.mn', function() { });

Comment: @Aamir i do have $(function(){...}) in my included JS.Strange really...

Comment: The direct use of `.click()` instead of `.on("click")` works just for elements already on the DOM tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use delegation, as your new elements are not present on the DOM tree at the moment you load the script.
This way, the event handler will be attached to every new element that attends the selector.

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul.menu li span.mn', function() { 
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') )
        return;     

    $('ul.nav li span.mn').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    selectedMenu = $(this).attr('rel');     
    displaySearchOptions();
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') )
        return; is correct.What this does is if current element is already selected ,it will return which is not the case here.If not it will remove selected class from previously selected element and assigns selected class to current selected element.It is working finr now.i had a typo and had used a different class name "nav" instead of "menu".Now i corrected it and its working fine.